# SSIS - Insert records and update records with lookup transformation

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am new to SSIS and have been tasked with taking records from a source table and inserting new or updating existing tables in the target. I estimate in the region of 10-15 records per day at maximum.

I have investigated the Lookup Transformation object and this looks like it will do the job.

Both source and target table columns are identical. However, there is no unique key/value in target or source to perform the lookup on. The existing fields I have to work with and do the lookup on are Date or Load_Date...

How can I achieve only adding new records or updating existing records in the target without a key/ID field? Do I really need to add another ID column to compare source and target with? And if so, can someone tell me how to do this? The target table must not have a key/ID field, so if using key/ID field, it would need to be dropped after any inserts/updates are done.

Could this be achieved this using Load_Date? Currently all Load_Date values are NULL in target table, so would it be as simple as matching on Load_Date and if Load_Date is already populated, then do not load? If Load_Date is NULL, then load the record?

Thanks.

Comment: We are going to have a hard time providing an answer without data. But your lookup will need to have some sort of granularity. It can be date, it can be a business key, a business key can be multiple columns. What does the source contain? What are you determining whether this is an insert or an update?

Comment: Sorry for delayed response. I ended up going with HashBytes to create unique key on each view. Use this with a MERGE update/insert and it worked fine.